# How to Select an Element Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="mySignin">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal @loginGuid">
            <div class="captcha">
                <img class="imgCaptcha" title="@LocalizeHelper.GetLocalizeString("Click to change captcha code")" src="@Url.Action("CaptchaImage", "Account")" />
                <input type="text" class="inputCaptcha" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I select `<input type="text" class="inputCaptcha" />` using JQuery?

Comment: This is a very basic question. You should look through both http://learn.jquery.com and http://try.jquery.com before diving any further into jQuery.

Comment: Selecting dom elements is a basic paradigm in CSS. You should check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.` to target elements by **[class name](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)**:

```
$('.inputCaptcha')
```

I'd suggest you to go through jQuery **[official learning center](http://learn.jquery.com/)** to learn more about jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Your element has class attribute. You can use class selector to target it.

```
 var captchinp = $('.inputCaptcha');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select it by its class

```
$('.inputCaptcha')
```

or if you want to only select inputs with the class:

```
$('input[type=text].inputCaptcha')
```

Answer (score 0):

you may have some other elements rather that input elements with the class `inputCaptcha`, so target elements with more relevance by the selector give below.

Try,

```
$('input[type="text"].inputCaptcha')
```

Comment: Did you mean *be specific*? generic implies the other answers.

Comment: Yes. I don't want to select other `<input type="text" class="inputCaptcha" />` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class selector like below

```
$('.inputCaptcha')
```

but if you have other html element with same `class=inputCaptcha` and you want to select only input then use below

```
$('input[class="inputCaptcha"]')
```

Please see [JQuery Selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more details